# didFinishReceivingResourceWithName not being called

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm sending video over MC on an app I'm making, didStartReceivingResourceWithName is being called correctly. The NSProgress object associated with that callback reaches 101.0% and then didFinishReceivingResourceWithName is never called. Do you have any ideas? Heres the code in each.

```
func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) {
    print("Did start receiving resource")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.progressTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "progressManager", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.progress = progress
    }
}
func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.status.text = "Recieved!"
    }
    self.progressTimer.invalidate()
    let destinationPath  =
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("movie.mov")
    let fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do{
        try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(localURL, toURL: destinationPath)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    print("Did finish receiving resource")
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm also experiencing didFinishReceivingResourceWithName not being called.

Comment: did anyone find anything helpful to share ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when calling sendResource with the local URL to a video file that I created using AVAssetWriter. It turns out that I was calling sendResource on the video file before AVAssetWriter was finished writing the video. After I modified my code to call sendResource in the completion handler for .finishWriting, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Can you provide a couple lines of code that illustrate that solutions? Thanks.